# How to clone/duplicate gradient transparent pixels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, image-editing

I've been searching for hours and couldn’t find any tutorial on the web... Unbelievable. Am I the only one to face this??

I'm just looking for a method to clone some gradient transparent pixels (or are they called softened pixels? I don't know how to refer to them).

I tried using the clone tool of course (**obviously with the wrong settings - it worked now, couldn't change my comment below so clarifying here**). It works great with 'normal' pixels. But when you try it on 'gradient-transparent pixels', it doesn't clone them as 'gradient-transparent':
[image]

I also tried by making a copy of the selection into a new layer but here there's an overlapping:
[image]

And when I remove the selection from the layer below, it still doesn’t look good:
[image]

Could someone help me please??

Thank you!

---

Comment: The easiest way I think **would've been** to use a layer mask on a group to feather the image, rather than the eraser tool or whatever lead you to this result. That way you're not duplicating translucent pixels on top of translucent pixels.

Comment: **Why** aren't the semi-transparent pixels being cloned as semi transparent?? The Clone Stamp tool **will** honor source transparency. There's *something* about the layer structure you are not sharing. (I'm aware you may not know what that is.) You need to show the Layers Panel as well.

Comment: @Scott They are – but they're being drawn on top of not-invisible pixels, so you end up with something darker than each on their own. OP wants to copy the colour values from the source but keep the alpha channel from the destination – exactly like an alpha mask does.

Comment: Using the Clone Stamp Tool did the trick. It was the easiest solution: only took a few clicks! Guess I've been so focused on the Healing Brush that I forgot the existence of the Clone Stamp Tool... Damn feeling so stupid of not having just tried that one. Anyway thank you guys!

Comment: @Rolm the Healing brush usually does the "healing" of pixels. What you needed was replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is causing problem. I couldn't reproduce it maybe because I don't know about your artwork layers. I tried with ***Clone Stamp Tool*** and it works fine what you might need. For this, I would prefer *Clone Stamp Tool* over *Healing Brush Tool*.

1. Try rasterizing your layer (make sure you copy and hide your original layer in case you need it later) in case you've masked it for transparency (masking area might need adjustments if you prefer mask methods).
2. Make the brush hardness much less than 100% so you don't see clear edges.
3. Use *Clone Stamp Tool* and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for taking sample you need to replicate and then click at the place where you need it. It worked fine for me:

[image]

---

If you want to try the method of creating a new layer with selection of the area you need to replicate, you need to increase the feather value of the selection (`Select > Modify > Feather`) so you don't notice that unwanted overlap. When you say you removed the selection of your bottom layer, it won't make much difference in fixing that issue, because currently your selection feather is hard or 0.

Comment: The Clone Stamp Tool did the trick. It took just a few clicks as you've demonstrated in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Turn all transparency to a layer mask. Apply Layer > Layer Mask >From Transparency

Disable the mask, remove the solid layer fill color for ex. selecting it with the magic wand and pressing DEL. The fill color cause easily harmful stripes when cloning. Theoretically one could let it be as is.

Make the needed cloning or healing brush job.

Enable the layer mask. Spray to it black or white with low opacity soft brush for the needed new feathering if the old one isn't good. I guess it isn't.